# Granting device admin previlage to email account

Tags: security, email, gmail, exchange, device-administrator

I am connecting my gmail app(or any e mail application) to my office e mail using **exchange**. It asks me to add the mail app as a **Device administrator** for my phone. So that it can  **Erase all data**,**Set password rules** and the list goes on.

Is it safe to grant the previlage?
Can someone else erase my data or do anything to phone?

Comment: I don't think something as simple as an e-mail client should be granted those privileges. Are you sure you're using the official Gmail/Exchange apps?

Comment: @Arielle Yes I am using the official gmail app. Without those privileges the exchange account will not work. No problem in using google mail.